# App Framework UI: confirmation popup opens after button click -> clicking OK should take me to internet page

Tags: jquery, button, popup, confirmation

How can I manage the following?

> 1. Button click
> 2. Confirmation pop-up opens
> 3. Clicking OK should take me to a pre-defined internet page.

It should (must) be done with this basis code:

```
<script>
    function goo() {
        $("#afui").popup({
            title:"Note",
            message:"Choose Ok to open Google",
            cancelText:"Cancel",
            cancelCallback: function(){},
            doneText:"Ok",
            doneCallback: function(){},
            cancelOnly:false
        });
    }
</script>

<a class="button" onClick="goo()">Google</a>
```

How do I adapt the code, i.e. how do I insert the URL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

App framework provided an option to redirect to another div

```
doneCallback: function () {
   $.ui.loadContent("#div_id",false,false,"side");
 }
```

Following are the parameters used,

- target-String
- newtab-Boolean
- go-Boolean
- transition-String

use this link

http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api.php#$_ui_loadContent